# Introduction for glossary with glossaries package

Tags: glossaries

I'm using the `glossaries` package, with both a Glossary and List of acronyms. I'd like to make some general comments in the Glossary before the entries begin. Something like:

```
Many of the definitions echo those in Reference A, B. Readers are 
referred to these works for additional information about the terminology
used here.
```

Is there a command I can redefine in order to get access to the space between the heading and the first entry? I can't find anything in `glossaries-user.pdf` about it. I'd be happy to use `glossaries-extra` if that helps.

A MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{Blackbox}
{
  name=Blackbox models,
  sort=blackbox,
  description={--- In system identification, the term \emph{blackbox} modelling refers to the process of modelling a system through non-parametric techniques.}
}

\begin{document}

A reference to \gls{Blackbox}.

\newpage

\printglossary[title={Glossary}]

% Would like:

% Glossary
%
% Many of the definitions echo those in Reference A, B. Readers are 
% referred to these works for additional information about the terminology
% used here.
% 
% Blackbox models — In system identification, the term blackbox modelling 
%    refers to the process of modelling a system through non-parametric techniques, 
%    without knowledge of physical inner workings of the system, resulting 
%    in an empirical model. 1
%

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please provide a compilable document, minimal as possible, with the relevant packages (i.e. with `glossaries`) -- we don't like to start from scratch!

Comment: You can redefine `\glossarypreamble` before `\printglossaries`. This will affect all glossaries. For an individual glossary you can do, for example, `\setglossarypreamble[acronym]{preamble text here}`.

Comment: Thanks! I should have been able to figure that out. Maybe `preamble` is a weird word choice, given its special meaning in `LaTeX`!

Comment: Not so weird if you consider the meaning of the word preamble "a preliminary or preparatory statement; an introduction" :-)

Comment: It fits the lay meaning of the term, I agree, but it's unrelated to the LaTeX preamble, which is why I got confused. Thanks for the package though, Nicola! Next stop is to play around with `glossaries-extra`!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `\setglossarypreamble[main]{Your text}` or `\setglossarypreamble[acronym]{Some other text}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\setglossarypreamble[acronym]{foo foo}

\setglossarypreamble[main]{Many of the definitions echo those in Reference A, B. Readers are 
  referred to these works for additional information about the terminology
  used here.}


\newglossaryentry{Blackbox}
{
  name=Blackbox models,
  sort=blackbox,
  description={--- In system identification, the term \emph{blackbox} modelling refers to the process of modelling a system through non-parametric techniques.}
}

\begin{document}

A reference to \gls{Blackbox}.


\clearpage
\printglossary%[title={Glossary}]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This works. Also, I really appreciate the nearly instant response, and the edits to conform to the MWE. Thanks.

Comment: @Danny: You're welcome. In the very moment I was writing my comment above I remembered `\setglossarypreamble` command. (it's a little bit hidden -- see the section `Displaying Glossaries`

Comment: Yep, I had a look just now. I had searched the document for `introduction`, `header`, `heading`, etc, but `preamble` didn't come to mind. Live and learn!